# Change "Windows font size (DPI)" in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, automation

I'm using a laptop at office (Windows 7) with a station and double screen and at home without station.

The point is I have to change text size each time I switch from station to standlone laptop, because the text size is too big on my double screen, but too small on my laptop screen.

To proceed:
I right-click on desk screen, choose change resolution then "get text and other elements bigger or smaller" to choose 100%, 125%, etc...
I need to restart my session to get the settings applied.
(Note: I'm using a French system, and texts are not exactly the same on us version I suppose).

It's not very convenient so I'd like to automate this, perhaps with a PowerShell script.

Ideally the script may detect if I'm using laptop alone or station with its two screens). Plus, without session restart (I doubt this last point is feasible).

How do I get started? If this is possible.

Comment: Even with powershell you will need to restart the session. I would suspect it is just a registry setting; and if so it might be overridden regularly in your environment. (In this case it sounds like a remote profile just doing it's thing.)

Answer (score 10):

This is the most straightforward method I've found. I lightly modified the provided function so it's an easy copy/paste. It does not require any registry calls or anything. Simple and very effective.

You can call it like this

```
function Set-Scaling {
    # Posted by IanXue-MSFT on
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/197944/batch-file-or-tool-like-powertoy-to-change-the-res.html
    # $scaling = 0 : 100% (default)
    # $scaling = 1 : 125% 
    # $scaling = 2 : 150% 
    # $scaling = 3 : 175% 
    param($scaling)
    $source = @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
    public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
                      uint uiAction,
                      uint uiParam,
                      uint pvParam,
                      uint fWinIni);
'@
    $apicall = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $source -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo -PassThru
    $apicall::SystemParametersInfo(0x009F, $scaling, $null, 1) | Out-Null
}

Set-Scaling -scaling 0
```

Comment: In contrast to the top answers, this worked on my Win 10 laptop.

Comment: This is absolutely the best answer. It works great on Windows 10. No logout. No restart. It just takes immediately effect.

Comment: @nevarDeath please slightly correct your script:
* If turned into a Set-FontScaling.ps1 script, the first line needs to be the last line (can't invoke a function before it is defined).
* The hyphen on "–PassThru" is not a true hyphen... it's a long dash. Please correct so that copy/paste works.

Answer (score 8):

As supposed in the other answers, the setting under HKLM is not the correct place as the dpi scaling is a user defined setting. The correct registry key is `HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop` with the value `LogPixels`.

More information about all DPI-related registry settings can be found in *[DPI-related APIs and registry settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528846.aspx#system)*.

I wrote a tiny PowerShell script that changes the DPI scaling depending on the current scaling and performs the user logoff, so I just have to execute the script when I put my device to a different monitor.

```
cd 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop'
$val = Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name "LogPixels"
if($val.LogPixels -ne 96)
{
    Write-Host 'Change to 100% / 96 dpi'
    Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name LogPixels -Value 96
} else {
    Write-Host 'Change to 150% / 144 dpi'
    Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name LogPixels -Value 144
}

logoff;exit
```

Comment: This is great!  On Windows 8, `logoff` didn't work so I changed it to `shutdown /L`

Comment: On Windows 10 20H2 with GPU graphic card not working.

Comment: Does this apply to any sized monitor? I found on a higher res monitor the setting of 192, and this corresponded to a 100 DPI. Resolution was set to 1024x768, native resolution is 2736 x 1824. Thanks

Comment: @dgm Dpi scaling is always a subjective setting. You should apply a value that gives you best readability and scaling on your monitor. I suggest you first try out with the normal Windows Settings App which scaling you want on your HiRes monitor. And then you change ``-Value 144`` in the script to the scaling value you found out, where 96 corresponds to 100% scaling, so e.g. 150% corresponds to a value of 144, 175% => 168, etc.

Comment: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dpi-related-apis-and-registry-settings?view=windows-11) on this question.

Comment: @dgm That documentation shows you what default scaling will be selected by Windows for a particular monitor. But in the end it's up to your personal preference. I had devices where Windows selected 150% scaling by default and I scaled down to 125% to get some more screen space. And on other devices, large 4K monitors, Windows set also 150% and I increased to 175% because I liked it better. You can chose whatever is best for you. That's why I answered your comment not with Documentation but with the advice to manually try out what scaling you really want on your monitor.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently you can set the `LogPixels` property of

```
HKLM:/Software/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/FontDPI
```

which is reiterated in a lot of places around the net. However, I got the impression that dpi was a user setting which makes no sense to have under HKLM.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I misread the question. I thought you wanted to control the PowerShell windows.

As already mentioned you could set the LogPixels setting in the registry, to see what the current setting is, try this:

```
Get-Item -Path Registry::'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property
```

If the LogPixels key is there it will show, you can create it if it does not exist:

```
Set-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI\LogPixels'
```

NB: You have to run this with privileges that allow you to manipulate the registry.

There is a good [introduction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156814.aspx) to this over at TechNet.

Comment: That's only the PowerShell host application. It has nothing to do with Windows settings.

Answer (score 1):

@Torben Schramme I found that I had to add one more ItemProperty Win8DpiScaling for this work.  But, I don't find the "logoff; exit" function working - I still have to do it manually.

```
cd 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop'
$val = Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name "LogPixels"
if($val.LogPixels -ne 96)
{
     Write-Host 'Change to 100% / 96 dpi'
     Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name LogPixels -Value 96
     Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name Win8DpiScaling 0
} else {
     Write-Host 'Change to 150% / 144 dpi'
     Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name LogPixels -Value 144
     Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name Win8DpiScaling 1
}
logoff;exit
```

Comment: It looks like you just duplicate the already presented answer.

Comment: I enhanced the answer.  You need to add Win8DpiScaling.

Comment: Maybe this extra line is needed if you are going to 100%.  But in my case I'm changing between 150% and 250% so I leave Win8DpiScaling on all the time.  I'm not really sure what difference it makes.

Answer (score 1):

After much time, I can't find anything in google.
Well, I made my own script:

```
$perfis = (Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_USERS\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "S-1"} | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty "Registry::$_\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name "Win8DpiScaling" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}).PSPath
foreach ($_ in $perfis) {Set-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::$_" -Name "Win8DpiScaling" -Value 0}

$monitores = (Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_USERS\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "S-1"} | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem "Registry::$_\Control Panel\Desktop\PerMonitorSettings" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}).PSPath
foreach ($_ in $monitores) {Set-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::$_" -Name "DpiValue" -Value 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

By comparing the output of `Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop'` before and after using the Windows GUI to set the scaling level, I found the following properties needed setting; worked for me:

```
cd 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop'
Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name LogPixels -Value 144
Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name Win8DpiScaling -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name FocusBorderHeight -Value 2
Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name FocusBorderWidth -Value 2
Write-Host 'Sign out and sign back in again to see changes.'
```

Answer (score -1):

Love this Answer, anyone have any idea on how to set for a single display instead of all at the same time? I have 3 monitors, and this is a universal change.

Set-Scaling -scaling 0

```
function Set-Scaling {
    # Posted by IanXue-MSFT on
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/197944/batch-file-or-tool-like-powertoy-to-change-the-res.html
    # $scaling = 0 : 100% (default)
    # $scaling = 1 : 125% 
    # $scaling = 2 : 150% 
    # $scaling = 3 : 175% 
    param($scaling)
$source = @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
    public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
                      uint uiAction,
                      uint uiParam,
                      uint pvParam,
                      uint fWinIni);
'@
    $apicall = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $source -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo –PassThru
    $apicall::SystemParametersInfo(0x009F, $scaling, $null, 1) | Out-Null
    }
```

Answer (score -9):

These simple steps worked for me:

1. Download Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3191566-x64.ZIP from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/install-configure
2. Unzip the file in tmp folder
3. Open a Powershell command window as Administrator, go in tmp folder where file has been unzipped and execute the following commands :

   set-executionpolicy remotesigned
   .\Install-WMF5.1.ps1

Comment: Explain what this has to do with the question asked.

Comment: Installing Windows Management Framework has nothing to do with the original question. Not sure why that is added to this question?