# Windows 10 System settings using CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

Can you change windows 10 system settings using cmd.
I try to make a batch file that change the Windows settings how i want them. 
Eexample : my screen is 100% and i want to make my screen 125% can i use a commannd for that ?
i was just wondering if its possible to change windows user options using a batch file. doesnt matter if its the monitor or other windows settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change "Windows font size (DPI)" in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365394/change-windows-font-size-dpi-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various Windows settings are controlled by Registry keys. You can find the right key for your particular setting by Google search. As an example, to change DPI scaling to 150%, save this script to *test.bat*, run from open Admin Cmd Prompt, then re-login:

```
@echo off
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v LogPixels /t reg_dword /d 144
exit /b
```

Comment: If the script works for you and you'll need more help in the future, pls  **Upvote** and **Accept** the answer by clicking both _Arrow Up_ and _Select_ signs to the left of the _Answer Box_.  Some novices don't know about these helpful features. :)

Comment: he's not a new comer. Look at [his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5935285/henk) and see he already accept an answer