# Execute a Powershell function from a BAT, CMD, or Console

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameters, dpi

I want to use this PowerShell `Set-Scaling` [DPI change script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68760240). However I'm having a hard time figuring out how to run it from a command-line with the appropriate parameters to set scale at 125%.

I tried the following one-line command in a batch file:

```bash
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -File ".\Set_Scale.ps1" Set-Scaling -scaling 1
```

However, it fails with the error:
[image: Error Message]

Can anyone PowerShell savvy please help?

[image: Sample Script screenshot]

I tried running the batch file to execute the function in the PowerShell script, trying to follow the examples of similar scripts on this forum and elsewhere on the internet without any luck.

===============================================

Update 2023-07-11

The BAT file and the PS1 file are both in the same folder so using the %~dp0 helped fix that first error. Now the BAT file runs without showing any errors but the Set_Scale.ps1 script does not do anything (See screenshot below).

To test further, I opened the Set_Scale.ps1 file in the PowerShell IDE and added a line "Set-Scaling -scaling(1)" to the top of the script as you can see in the next screenshot. This works perfectly. You might even notice the difference in display DPI between the two screenshots below.

Does anyone know why I can't do the same from the BAT file? I just want to execute the Set-Scaling function while passing the "1" value to it so that it scales the display to 125%

Results Sample 1 - Run from BAT not working
[image]

Results Sample 2 - Run from IDE works fine
[image]

Comment: Your error message is telling you the file doesn't exist. Have you tried using a fully qualified path to `Set_Scale.ps1`?

Comment: The `cmd.exe` window in your image clearly indicates that you have selected running 'As administrator'. This makes your current working directory `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, as also evident in the same image. Your problem is that you're using a lazy command which makes unnecessary guesses. A relative path, (i.e. `.\Set_Scale.ps1`), should only ever be used from a guaranteed/known working directory, which you've not defined. So either use the absolute path to the script, or specifically set the working directory before using a relative path.

Comment: The directory holding your running batch script is always `%~dp0.`, so you could, in such a case use either `CD /D "%~dp0"`, or `PushD "%~dp0"` to define the working directory. Alternatively use `"%~dp0Set_Scale.ps1"` in your batch file argument to powershell.exe.